# limit of dominated sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Assume we have two positive valued sequences: $X_{n}$ and $Y_{n}$. Next, assume that
$$
X_{n}\overset{d}{\to} X
$$
and for all $n$ we have
$$
Y_{n} \leq X_{n}.
$$
Next, assume that $F_{X}$ is cdf of $X$. Is the following correct, that for all continuity point a of $F_{X}(x)$ we have
$$
\limsup_{n} P(Y_n \leq a) \geq F_{X}(a)?
$$

**Try:**
Since $X_{n}\overset{d}{\to} X$, then
$$
\limsup_{n} P(X_n \leq a) = F_{X}(a).
$$
Next, since $Y_{n} \leq X_{n}$ then $\{\omega\in\Omega: X_{n}\leq a\} \subset \{\omega\in\Omega: Y_{n}\leq a\}$. Therefore, $P(Y_{n}\leq a) \geq P(X_{n}\leq a)$, which proves the statement.

Comment: Isn't this a consequence of the dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: I do not recognise...

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong. Please take $X_n \sim \mathcal{U}[1,2] , Y_n=1$ and $a=1.5$ to see a contradiction.

Comment: I apologise, I did a mistake in statement of the question and in suggested solution

Comment: @LrM: Then your solution is correct to me. I am now unsure of what you want to ask